# How does a website know I'm using a proxy?

Tags: python, proxy

I am able to connect to the verizon site from my machine:

```
>>> import requests
>>> res=requests.get('https://tv.verizon.com/api/fullSearch/as/rows/30/start/0?assetTypeCode=movies')
>>> res
<Response [200]>
```

However, if I use a proxy -- which is working on another site, such as Google -- it does not return a response:

```
>>> res=requests.get(
    'https://tv.verizon.com/api/fullSearch/as/rows/30/start/0?assetTypeCode=movies', 
     proxies={
        'http': 'http://xx:yy@23.82.141.126:29842' ,
        'https': 'http://xx:yy@23.82.141.126:29842'}
   )
[ request just hangs... ]
```

But on another site it works:

```
    >>> res=requests.get(
...         'https://google.com', 
...          proxies={
...             'http': 'http://xx:yy@23.88.141.126:29842',
...             'https': 'http://xx:yy@23.88.141.126:29842'}
...        )
>>> res
<Response [200]>
```

Why is this occurring? And how would I successfully request Verizon with a proxy?

Comment: Probably because Verizon is intentionally dropping packets from those proxies... probably because they've received malicious requests from them in the past. Although if it's "hanging", it might just be taking forever to make it through the proxies.

Comment: This seems like a broad question. How do you know for sure it's that you're using a proxy? Maybe you can reformulate it so that you can get help with using a proxy? Either way this doesn't seem like a clear question to me (at least with my near complete inexperience with proxies)

Comment: @TemporalWolf I don't think so -- I've never used these proxies before. I'm just testing it now.

Comment: There are plenty of ways to [block proxies](https://perishablepress.com/how-to-block-proxy-servers-via-htaccess/). And if you're using a public proxy, then just because you haven't abused it doesn't mean others haven't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know the [tor](https://torproject.org) network uses a public exit node list available [here](https://check.torproject.org/cgi-bin/TorBulkExitList.py). It may be possible the site you wish to connect to is using such a lookup table/list.

Reason for this is that proxies are often used to hide fradulent actions like hacking or overloading servers (Denial of service attacks). Dropping the connection makes it much much harder to do a Denial of service attack from proxies.

Please note: I used tor as an example here. There may be other list(s) involved here